# Bankruptcy discharged in 2004 and Consumer Proposal in Jan. 2015: Worthwhile to try to apply for a mortgage now?

Tags: canada, bankruptcy, mortgage-qualification

I assume that mortgage lenders can no longer see my aunt's bankruptcy (that my aunt's credit reports do not show) because it is past 7 years.

Now responsibly using 2 Credit Cards, my aunt accepts that mortgage lenders prefer at least 2 years of clean credit and 2 Lines of Credit.  My aunt is renting and must move, but prefers and can now afford a mortgage.

Even if [the Consumer Proposal can be seen by mortgage lenders until Jan. 2018](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/66174/44214), should my aunt try: to apply for (1) an affordable mortgage now and (2) to seek an interest rate < 4%?

Or is (1), (2) so unlikely for her that she should not even try? If so, she will find somewhere to rent and forget about a mortgage until Jan. 2017. Thank you.

Comment: Get screwed on housing price later, or get screwed on interest rate now, decisions decisions

Comment: @CQM 'Get screwed on housing price later' : What do you mean? That house prices will continue to rise in Canada?

Comment: Yes that's what I was referring to